# Cannot send embed in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to make a simple discord bot with discord.py with slash commands and an embed, but I keep getting the error: `_Context.send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'embed'`.

Here is my code:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True


bot = interactions.Client(token=TOKEN)


@bot.command(
  name="debug",
  description="Test for errors in bot",
  scope=<id>,
)
async def debug(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
  help_embed = discord.Embed(title="Modules:")
  
  await ctx.send(embed=help_embed)


bot.start()
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `scope=<id>` valid syntax?

Comment: its a placeholder for the actual guild id, i'm not sure if its safe to share it online

Answer (score 0):

According to the `interactions.py` framework documentation, the [Context.send](https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/context.html#interactions.client.context.CommandContext.send) has the `embeds` argument (not `embed`).

You seem to be confusing the `interactions.py` library with `discord.py`. It's so much so that you're using both at the same time to create two different bots and run them at the same time. This is crazy!
You need to choose one of them to develop your bot. If you choose `interactions.py`:

```py
import interactions


bot = interactions.Client(TOKEN)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.me.name}')


@bot.command(
    name="debug",
    description="Test for errors in bot"
)
async def debug(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    help_embed = interactions.Embed(title="Modules:")
    await ctx.send(embeds=help_embed)


client.start()
```

For more info:

- [Small example](https://github.com/interactions-py/interactions.py/blob/stable/examples/bot.py) of how to create a bot with interactions.py;
- interactions.py [documentation](https://discord-interactions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: i was only using the interactions library, i forgot to delete the extra code. when running your example i ran into: `'interactions' has no attribute 'listen'` and KeyError: <Object id=<id> type=<class 'discord.object.Object'>>

Comment: I updated the code fixing the fist issue. About the second, I think you didn't replace the guild id in `scope`. But I'm removing this argument, so the command will be global

Answer (score 0):

syntax and wrong references.
( i think )

```py
@bot.command(
  name="debug",
  description="Test for errors in bot",
  guild=discord.Object(id=GUILD_ID),
)
async def commands(interaction: discord.Interaction):
  commands = bot.get_commands(guild=discord.Object(id=GUILD_ID))

  embed = discord.Embed(title="Debug",
                        description="",
                        color=discord.Color.blue())

  embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://4dabloo.nz/4dabloons.jpg")
  embed.add_field(name="Client Commands:",
                  value="\n".join([
                    f"**{command.name}** :white_check_mark: "
                    for command in commands
                  ]),
                  inline=False)

  await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```